# PHPMailer on remote host does't work

Tags: wamp, phpmailer

I'm working on a little e-cards project. 
I have to send emails from my remote server with PHPMailer.

localy I'm using this configuration (with my own Gmail email adress) and it works perfectly.

/ssi/mail.config.php

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet      = 'utf-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port         = '587';
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = 'private@gmail.com';
$mail->Password     = '***secret***';
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';
?>
```

On my remote server (hosted on one.com) I have created an email account for the domain.
I changed the host and the port like the helpdesk said ... but I don't get it to work remotly.

```
<?php
'ssi/mail.config.php'
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet      = 'utf-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = 'send.one.com';
$mail->Port         = '25';
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'none';
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = 'ecards@iveweygers.be';
$mail->Password     = '***secret***';
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'none';
?>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you not just use the php `mail` function?

Comment: does your host allow SMTP Authentication? or have you enabled it?

Comment: The normal php mail() function acts a little buggy, but I don't tried to send mails with that one remotely. Yes outbound mails from a webpage is supported, only from there SMTP server with an email in the domain.

Comment: are you allowed access to change your allowed email ports on your server? your internet service will block ports sometimes. for example and this is a random internet service not mine. they block port 25: http://support.cableone.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/1066/~/blocked-ports

Comment: If you have SMTPDebug set to 2 then surely you have some error messages to share with us?  You can set it to 4 for an even more verbose response.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the one.com page, there are a few things wrong with this.  For smtp they say to use Port 465 with SSL encryption.  So, your code should be:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet      = 'utf-8'; // You can remove this line, utf-8 is the default.
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = 'send.one.com';
$mail->Port         = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = 'ecards@iveweygers.be';
$mail->Password     = '***secret***';
```

Also worth noting -- and something that it took me a LONG time to find:  My SMTP server required authentication to send an email.  I assumed that the `SMTPAuth = true;` took care of that but it did not.  I noticed that one.com does as well -- i.e. they tell you to click the button in Outlook that says that your outgoing server requires authentication.

I finally got it to work by putting this at the top of my file:

```
$pop = new POP3();
$pop->Authorise("send.one.com", 465, 30, "ecards@iveweygers.be", "***secret_password***", 1);
```

That takes care of the authentication.  Then you can jump into the `$mail = new PHPMailer(true)` and setting all of your parameters and sending the mail.

So your entire file should look like this:

```
$pop = new POP3();
$pop->Authorise("send.one.com", 465, 30, "ecards@iveweygers.be", "***secret_password***", 1);



$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet      = 'utf-8'; // You can remove this line, utf-8 is the default.
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = 'send.one.com';
$mail->Port         = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = 'ecards@iveweygers.be';
$mail->Password     = '***secret***';
```

Comment: Hi this works perfectly! Thanks for your work and time! I already had maked the switch to the normal php mail() function. But now I can use this PHPMailer configuration. :) Thanks again

Comment: BTW UTF-8 is not the default `CharSet` in PHPMailer; it is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: You really found a host that still uses POP-before-SMTP auth?? I think I last saw that in the early 1990s...

Answer (score 2):

You have not said how it's failing, which makes diagnosis difficult.

I really wouldn't recommend any service that uses authentication without encryption. There is no meaning to setting `SMTPSecure` to 'none' - just set it to an empty string (or don't set it at all) if you don't want SSL or TLS, and you only need to do that once (not twice as in your code).

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions did not work for me; this one did:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                            // disable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '[your one.com-email]';
$mail->Password = '[your one.com-email password]';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // leave this blank!
$mail->Port = 25;
```

Let me know if it helped you, too!