# Sending email getting error as Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have implemented mail functionality to my website but getting error while sending email.I have added PHPMailer to my website and added code but getting this error. Changed with host as well by checking in google but still getting the same error.

```
2019-07-06 06:55:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO website.com
2019-07-06 06:55:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2019-07-06 06:55:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_contact']))  
{
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$to = "XXXX@gmail.com";

$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none'; 
$mail->Host = "localhost";    
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);                          
$mail->Username = "XXXXX@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "PASSXXX";                           
$mail->SSL=False;

$message = array();    
$message[]= 'Name  :  '.trim($name).' ';
$message[]='Phone  :  '.trim($contact).' ';   
$message[]='Email  :  '.trim($email).' ';   
$message[]='Message  :  '.trim($textarea).' '; 
$message = implode('<br/>', $message);  

$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->Subject = 'Regarding Pure Gir Cow Milk';
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($to); 

if(!$mail->send()) {
$msg = "Error while sending email";
$msgclass = 'bg-danger';    
 } else {
$msg = 'Successfully Sent.';
$msgclass = 'bg-success';   
}
}
?>
```

Comment: There some parameter not correct. For example `$mail->SMTPSecure = '';` not none. Please have a look at the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747645/phpmailer-on-remote-host-doest-work

Comment: I recommend you delete this question. It has been answered many times before, and the solution you posted is a "works for me" that provides no insight as to what the problem might be. You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, so I suggest you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none'; 
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";    
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);                          
$mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";                           
$from = $email; // Reply to this email
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
```